# How to get get categories and sub - categories Query Builder in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Good day. I am designing an API from the table below. The database I am working with is a poorly designed legacy database.

Now,the titles are under a category. Like, Title, B, C, D are under Cat B. So, want to return two nodes. Node 1 - returning all the categories, and node 2 - returning an array of all the titles under the category.

I am using Laravel Query Builder. I can get the categories with the code below. The problem now is with getting the titles under it.

```
$rows = DB::connection('mysql3')
            ->table('tbl_form')
            ->selectRaw("DISTINCT UPPER(LTRIM(`type`)) as category")
            ->where('deleted', 0)
            ->orderBy('category', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Please, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with [eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_form'; // 'posts'

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'category', 'category')->select(['title']);
    }
}
```

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_form'; // 'posts'

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category', 'category');
    }
}
```

And retrieve it like that:

```
$categories = Category::all();
dd($categories[0]->posts);
```

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting error 'posts method not defined'

Comment: Can you please post the whole stack trace because right now I've no idea why this error occoures.