# Attach result of for loop to eloquent output in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, eloquent

Good day. Like I explained in this post [Using Query Builder and MySql to get categories and sub - categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936847/using-query-builder-and-mysql-to-get-categories-and-sub-categories), I want to make something meaningful from this table. I decided to go the Eloquent way. I am able to get the distinct categories as shown below. How do i loop through each title belonging to a a particular category?
For example, get it in the form:

**CatA**

```
Title 1
Title 5
```

**CatB**

```
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
```

My code is shown below

```
public function type(Request $request){
    
    $details = [];

    $categories = Category::distinct()->get(['category']); //Get the distinct categories from the category column in the table


    foreach($categories as $category){
      $titles = Category::where('type',$category->type);
      $details = ['cat'=>$category->type,[
          'title' => $titles->title,
          'pk' => $titles->pk
      ]];
    }

    return response()->json([
         "Data" => $details
    ]);
}
```

Not getting a result. Is there a better way this can be done please?

Comment: I'd use two models `Category` and `Title`. Otherwise you mess your models a bit up.

Comment: what is the result you get with the code you show? It seems that what you need there is a gruopBy

Answer (score 0):

You can make many to many relationship with post and category. Then get all categories with posts.

Example:

```
$categories = Category::with('posts')->all();
```

Then you can loop through categories and posts

```
foreach($categories as $category){
   foreach($category->posts as $post){
      echo $post->title;
   }
}
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it was not working because the categories have to be distinct first.

Comment: $categories = Category::with('posts')->distinct()->get(['type']); is returning an empty array for posts

Comment: $categories = Category::with('posts')->distinct()->get(['type']); is returning an empty array for posts